# Getting error when trying to read JSON for BigQuery table

Tags: json, google-bigquery

Trying to load regular JSON file from BigQuery table and it errors out.
Error:"Error while reading data, error message: Failed to parse JSON: Unexpected end of string; Unexpected end of string;"

JSON file:

```
{
  "processorName": "bankruptcy_processor",
  "versionName": "bk_version_v1",
  "isFuzzyMatch": true,
  "createTime": "2023-03-04T05:24:03.203501Z",
  "metrics": {
    "All labels": {
      "f1Score": 0.85383502170767,
      "precision": 0.8702064896755162,
      "recall": 0.8380681818181818,
      "evaluatedDocuments": 37,
      "testDocuments": 37,
      "invalidDocuments": 0,
      "failedDocuments": 0
    },
    "document_date": {
      "f1Score": 0.7692308,
      "precision": 0.7777778,
      "recall": 0.76086956,
      "optimalConfidence": 0.11,
      "predictedInstancesCount": 45,
      "predictedDocumentsCount": 28,
      "groundtruthInstancesCount": 46,
      "groundtruthDocumentsCount": 31,
      "confidenceThreshold": 0.11
    },
    "borrower_address": {
      "f1Score": 0.8205128,
      "precision": 1,
      "recall": 0.6956522,
      "optimalConfidence": 0.17,
      "predictedInstancesCount": 16,
      "predictedDocumentsCount": 13,
      "groundtruthInstancesCount": 23,
      "groundtruthDocumentsCount": 18,
      "confidenceThreshold": 0.17
    },
    "date_filed": {
      "f1Score": 0.6428572,
      "precision": 0.6,
      "recall": 0.6923077,
      "optimalConfidence": 0,
      "predictedInstancesCount": 15,
      "predictedDocumentsCount": 11,
      "groundtruthInstancesCount": 13,
      "groundtruthDocumentsCount": 10,
      "confidenceThreshold": 0
    },
    "borrower_name": {
      "f1Score": 0.85393256,
      "precision": 0.88372093,
      "recall": 0.82608694,
      "optimalConfidence": 0.83,
      "predictedInstancesCount": 129,
      "predictedDocumentsCount": 37,
      "groundtruthInstancesCount": 138,
      "groundtruthDocumentsCount": 37,
      "confidenceThreshold": 0.83
    },
    "case_number": {
      "f1Score": 0.97029704,
      "precision": 0.9607843,
      "recall": 0.98,
      "optimalConfidence": 0,
      "predictedInstancesCount": 102,
      "predictedDocumentsCount": 37,
      "groundtruthInstancesCount": 100,
      "groundtruthDocumentsCount": 37,
      "confidenceThreshold": 0
    },
    "SSN": {
      "f1Score": 0.71875,
      "precision": 0.71875,
      "recall": 0.71875,
      "optimalConfidence": 0,
      "predictedInstancesCount": 32,
      "predictedDocumentsCount": 21,
      "groundtruthInstancesCount": 32,
      "groundtruthDocumentsCount": 21,
      "confidenceThreshold": 0
    }
  }
}
```

Trying to load JSON file data into BigQuery. It errors out stating not being JSON file.

Comment: Hi there, the json above is not readable to understand the issue better. however, can you please ensure the json data follows this https://jsonlines.org/

Answer (score 1):

I edited your post to add code blocks around the JSON - I am assuming that is what your file looks like? As [Bihag Kashikar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20696779/bihag-kashikar) said, you need JSON-L, which is new-line delimited JSON.

Format the whole JSON struct on one line and it will work:

```
{ "processorName": "bankruptcy_processor", "versionName": "bk_version_v1", "isFuzzyMatch": true, "createTime": "2023-03-04T05:24:03.203501Z", "metrics": { "All_labels": { "f1Score": 0.85383502170767, "precision": 0.8702064896755162, "recall": 0.8380681818181818, "evaluatedDocuments": 37, "testDocuments": 37, "invalidDocuments": 0, "failedDocuments": 0 }, "document_date": { "f1Score": 0.7692308, "precision": 0.7777778, "recall": 0.76086956, "optimalConfidence": 0.11, "predictedInstancesCount": 45, "predictedDocumentsCount": 28, "groundtruthInstancesCount": 46, "groundtruthDocumentsCount": 31, "confidenceThreshold": 0.11 }, "borrower_address": { "f1Score": 0.8205128, "precision": 1, "recall": 0.6956522, "optimalConfidence": 0.17, "predictedInstancesCount": 16, "predictedDocumentsCount": 13, "groundtruthInstancesCount": 23, "groundtruthDocumentsCount": 18, "confidenceThreshold": 0.17 }, "date_filed": { "f1Score": 0.6428572, "precision": 0.6, "recall": 0.6923077, "optimalConfidence": 0, "predictedInstancesCount": 15, "predictedDocumentsCount": 11, "groundtruthInstancesCount": 13, "groundtruthDocumentsCount": 10, "confidenceThreshold": 0 }, "borrower_name": { "f1Score": 0.85393256, "precision": 0.88372093, "recall": 0.82608694, "optimalConfidence": 0.83, "predictedInstancesCount": 129, "predictedDocumentsCount": 37, "groundtruthInstancesCount": 138, "groundtruthDocumentsCount": 37, "confidenceThreshold": 0.83 }, "case_number": { "f1Score": 0.97029704, "precision": 0.9607843, "recall": 0.98, "optimalConfidence": 0, "predictedInstancesCount": 102, "predictedDocumentsCount": 37, "groundtruthInstancesCount": 100, "groundtruthDocumentsCount": 37, "confidenceThreshold": 0 }, "SSN": { "f1Score": 0.71875, "precision": 0.71875, "recall": 0.71875, "optimalConfidence": 0, "predictedInstancesCount": 32, "predictedDocumentsCount": 21, "groundtruthInstancesCount": 32, "groundtruthDocumentsCount": 21, "confidenceThreshold": 0 } } }
```

(It also complains about `All labels` not being a valid column name because of the space, so I added an underscore.)